# Patching diff-files

Tags: git, diff, patch

I've downloaded a tarballed version of 0.85 "MTR" -> http://www.bitwizard.nl/mtr/
and installed it.

I later saw that a 0.86 diff file exists. I downloaded this in order to patch it, but am confused how to use the patch command. The first thing that bothers me is that I need to know the originalfile name, right? But there is no file in the folder called mtr.0.85 or something along those lines.

How would I know what the originalfile is? Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Edit:
The diff-file has the following content, but I've tried those commands all to no avail.

```
INSTALLING diff --git a/SECURITY b/SECURITY index 6cfc40b..4ff73a9 100644 --- a/SECURITY +++ b/SECURITY @@ -7,15 +7,16 @@ minimal. Or you can make mtr setuid-root, and the following applies to you...`
```

Running "patch mtr mtr-0.86.diff" renders the following output:
HUNK #1 FAILED AT 16..  until all 9 hunks fails.

ftp://ftp.bitwizard.nl/mtr/mtr-0.86.diff

Comment: Please use the [edit] button underneath your post to add additional information.

Comment: That's either a corrupted patch file or you've broken its formatting

Comment: @roaima it is only a extract from the file. the total contents can be found here: ftp://ftp.bitwizard.nl/mtr/mtr-0.86.diff

Answer (score 2):

What you have is an output from *git diff* (not the usual `diff` command).  You would not use the usual `patch` program to apply it.  Instead, you would use a git tool "apply".

Further reading:

- [How to read the output from git diff`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529441/how-to-read-the-output-from-git-diff)
- [git-diff - Show changes between commits, commit and working tree, etc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff)
- [git-apply - Apply a patch to files and/or to the index](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply)
- [How to create and apply a patch with Git](https://ariejan.net/2009/10/26/how-to-create-and-apply-a-patch-with-git/)

Comment: Tried it, renders only problems (git apply mtr-0.86.diff)

Comment: Funny thing is when I ran the "git apply --check mtr-0.86.diff" command, it rendered no problems. then I ran the git apply again, and some output were shown in the terminal. When I run the check again, it says "does not apply" but version is still 0.85. This is doing my head in

Comment: But git status might show that there are modifications, and that those can be committed.  Once you've applied the patch, there's nothing to apply from it, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If `git(1)` gave the diff, you have to use `git apply` (`git` uses most of the `diff(1)` unified format, but adds some git-specific handling).

If applying the patch fails, either (a) the patch got corrupted (i.e., lines deleted/mutilated, tabs expanded, different line ending conventions), or (b) you are trying to apply the patch to a *different* base (it should work if there are no overlapping modifications, and changes didn't move the places patched too much).

If the patch doesn't apply, you should get a file with the rejects as a byproduct, you can then try to apply the missing changes by hand. Just make sure you save intermediate stages frequently, having to redo the whole mess because of a misapplied change some 30 hunks into the rejects is no fun.

If this exists under `git` control somewhere, it is probably easier to ask permission to pull/clone.